# Setting charset in php

Tags: php, character-encoding, http-headers

How to send data in php with ANSI charset ?
As defaults is UTF-8

I use:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ansi');
```

without  effects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by ANSI you mean "Windows Western", you should use `charset=windows-1252` rather than us-ascii.

Answer (score 2):

`"text/plain; charset=us-ascii"`, see RFC http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html

Comment: unfortunately it did not help.
Charset sets itself depending on the data that I send.
`mb_convert_encoding` function  helped :)